# Representing sequence of probability-assigned values into mathematical relations

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, mathematical-modeling

I'm just having a bit of trouble representing this situation in mathematical terms:

I start with a sequence of values, say [x, y, z, a, b, c]. I want to generate a new sequence of values from that sequence of values by assigning each index/element of the original sequence with a probability (between 0 and 1) and then selecting only the values greater than some threshold t to be put into the generated sequence. So, the sequence could have any number of elements between 0 and the original length of sequence.

I'm just trying to think of a way to use mathematical equations to represent that. I was thinking of doing something like:

new[n] = {keep if prob(old[n])>t} but that doesn't capture the sense that index n is the next number that is greater than value t.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see the significance of the probability here. The selection criteria seems to be whether a given value exceeds the threshold value. Or are you saying that an element $x_i$ of the original list is only chosen as a candidate with probability $p_i$?

Comment: Yeah basically it's whether a given value exceeds the threshold value. For instance, if the threshold value is 0.5 then there would be a 50% probability of it being chosen. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, not at all. For example you could have a list of values $(1,2,3,4,5)$ and probabilities $(1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,1/6)$, with a threshold value of $2$. In this case the values $1$ and $2$ would be rejected automatically, but the values $3$, $4$, and $5$ may or may not be rejected. Your question is not stated precisely, and as such cannot be answered precisely.